# How can I use the google maps api v3 in arc2earth?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, arcgis

I've imported the google maps street layer with arc2earth and produced a new one, and I show it in a web site with the google api v3 and the streets layer generated by me doesn't match the google maps street layer, and that happens because arc2earth uses the maps from the google api v2. And nobody believes me. I've talked with arc2earth and google support, and both say that the maps are the same.

But I have proofs:
for example in this location it is very clear how different they are:
19.369818,-99.261531
(mexico city)

You can check the v2 here:
[http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v2-geocoder-tool.html#q%3D19.369818%2C-99.261531](http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/v2-geocoder-tool.html#q=19.369818,-99.261531) (zoom in please)

and the v3 in the official google maps page:
http://maps.google.com/maps?q=19.368376,-99.263443&hl=en&ll=19.369684,-99.261244&spn=0.00143,0.002411&sll=19.369722,-99.261295&sspn=0.00144,0.002411&vpsrc=6&t=m&z=19

Comment: Your two links seem to pull up the same location.  I'm not seeing the difference you're talking about.

Comment: @Trott Yes both are from the same location, but the maps are different. I just bought the premium license of A2E and it uses the v3 maps and the community(free) license uses the v2 maps. I just got bad information from A2E support, Thanks.

Comment: Cool.  If you've solved your problem, post the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
The A2E community edition(Trial) uses the v2 maps. All the paid editions uses the v3 maps.